# Tensorflow Adagrad optimizer isn't working

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network

When I run the following script, I notice the following couple of errors:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import random

#set random seed:
random.seed(42)

def potential(N):

    points  = np.random.rand(N,2)*10

    values = np.array([np.exp((points[i][0]-5.0)**2 + (points[i][1]-5.0)**2) for i in range(N)])

    return points, values



def init_weights(shape,var_name):
    """
        Xavier initialisation of neural networks
    """

    init = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
    return tf.get_variable(initializer=init,name = var_name,shape=shape)

def neural_net(X):

    with tf.variable_scope("model",reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):

        w_h = init_weights([2,10],"w_h")
        w_h2 = init_weights([10,10],"w_h2")
        w_o = init_weights([10,1],"w_o")

        ### bias terms:
        bias_1 = init_weights([10],"bias_1")
        bias_2 = init_weights([10],"bias_2")
        bias_3 = init_weights([1],"bias_3")

        h = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, w_h),bias_1))
        h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(h, w_h2),bias_2))

    return tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(h2, w_o),bias_3))

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

with tf.Session() as sess:

    model = neural_net(X)

    ## define optimizer:
    opt = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.0001)

    values =tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]) 

    squared_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(model-values))   

    ## define model variables:
    model_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,"model")
    train_model = opt.minimize(squared_loss,var_list=model_vars)

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(10):

        points, val = potential(100)

        train_feed = {X : points,values: val.reshape((100,1))}

        sess.run(train_model,feed_dict = train_feed)
        print(sess.run(model,feed_dict = {X:points}))

    ### plot the approximating model:
    res = 0.1
    xy = np.mgrid[0:10:res, 0:10:res].reshape(2,-1).T

    values = sess.run(model, feed_dict={X: xy})    
    sns.heatmap(values.reshape((int(10/res),int(10/res))),xticklabels=False,yticklabels=False)
```

1. On the first run I get:

> [nan]  [nan]  [nan]  [nan]  [nan]  [nan]  [nan]] Traceback (most
>   recent call last):
>
> ...
>
> File
>   "/Users/aidanrockea/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py",
>   line 485, in heatmap
>       yticklabels, mask)
>
> File
>   "/Users/aidanrockea/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py",
>   line 167, in **init**
>       cmap, center, robust)
>
> File
>   "/Users/aidanrockea/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/matrix.py",
>   line 206, in _determine_cmap_params
>       vmin = np.percentile(calc_data, 2) if robust else calc_data.min()
>
> File
>   "/Users/aidanrockea/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py",
>   line 29, in _amin
>       return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
>
> ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has
>   no identity

2. On the second run I have:

> ValueError: Variable model/w_h/Adagrad/ already exists, disallowed.
>   Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?

It's not clear to me why I get either of these errors. Furthermore, when I use:

```
for i in range(10):

    points, val = potential(10)

    train_feed = {X : points,values: val.reshape((10,1))}
    sess.run(train_model,feed_dict = train_feed)
    print(sess.run(model,feed_dict = {X:points}))
```

I find that on the first run, I sometimes get a network that has collapsed to the constant function with output 0. Right now my hunch is that this might simply be a numerics problem but I might be wrong.

If so, it's a serious problem as the model I have used here is very simple.

Comment: Adding the complete console message instead of just the error line might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now my hunch is that this might simply be a numerics problem

indeed, when running `potential(100)` I sometimes get values as large as `1E21`. The largest points will dominate your loss function and will drive the network parameters.

Even when normalizing your target values e.g. to unit variance, the problem of the largest values dominating the loss would still remain (look e.g. at `plt.hist(np.log(potential(100)[1]), bins = 100)`).

If you can, try learning the log of `val` instead of `val` itself. Note however that then you are changing the assumption of the loss function from 'predictions follow a normal distribution around the target values' to 'log predictions follow a normal distribution around log of the target values'.